# XML is overwritten after saving it with Configuration and LINQ-to-XML?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, configurationmanager

I am opening up an `XML` file using `LINQ-to-XML`, but before this I am using `OpenMappedExeConfiguration` to get the `ConnectionStringsSection` from the config file:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = exeConfigName;
System.Configuration.Configuration config =
ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);`

ConnectionStringsSection section = config.ConnectionStrings;

//Modify connection string...
```

After I modify part of a `ConnectionString`, I save the config file via:

```
config.Save();
```

After saving the `EXE configuration`, I open the file again to read some other parts via `LINQ-to-XML`, but after calling `Save()` on the document,  it appears to not save my `ConnectionString` changes, but it saves the changes I made with `LINQ-to-XML`.

```
XDocument configFile = XDocument.Load(path);

//make changes to configFile

XDocument.Save(path);
```

I had to move the `EXE configuration` code below the `XDocument` code. I can see it changing the `ConnectionString` in memory before it hits the `XDocument` code. I am not sure why this is happening, but is it because I have loaded XML into memory and when I save it back, I am essentially overwriting all changes I made with my `config.Save()`?  If this is so, is there a way I can make changes without having to reorder the code?

Comment: How are you verifying that the two Saves are physically writing to the file? Are you relying on what's in memory? Or actually examining the file? Did you try calling `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(section)` to force the application to reload the config file?

Comment: Before it hits the break point of saving the file through LINQ-to-XML, I am physically examining the file.